# Specifying direction of rule in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle, hol

I have found the same problem when proving several lemmas: rules with an equality sometimes only work in one direction.

For instance, I'd like to use `append_assoc` to get from `xs @ ys @ zs` to `(xs @ ys) @ zs`, but since `append_assoc` is defined as `(xs @ ys) @ zs = xs @ ys @ zs`, I can't.

Is there any way to indicate I want to use some rule backwards?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule with swapped left- and right-hand sides is obtained by applying an attribute `symmetric` to the original rule:

```
lemma "xs @ ys @ zs = (xs @ ys) @ zs"
  by (rule append_assoc [symmetric])
```